# Populate items from an array into different options tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I am trying to load some usernames returned via ajax into a dropdown menu using jQuery. The results are successfully getting into the dropdown menu but all the data is getting into just one option tag. I want the data to be in different option tags.

Currently the dropdown menu looks like this

Name1,Name2,Name3,Name4

But I want as:

Name1

Name2

Name3

Name4

Dropdown where I am putting the results:

```
    <div class="form-group">
    <select name="name" class="form-control" id="employee_select">
</select>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
    //send value via GET to URL
    var get_request = $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/users',
      data: {User:User}
    });

    // handle response
    get_request.done(function(data){

    // Data returned
    dataReturned = data;

    // Log data
   console.log($.type(dataReturned));   // response is string in the form of
                                         // Name1
                                         // Name2

   // Convert to an array
   dataArray = [dataReturned]

    // Create a new array
    newArray = [];

// Populate newArray with items
for(i=0;i<dataArray.length;i++){
   if(typeof(dataArray[i])=='string'){
    newArray.push(dataArray[i])
}
}
//console.log(newArray);
console.log($.type(newArray)); // an array is returned in the form of ["Name1,Name2,Name3,Name4"]

// Loop through newArray
$.each(newArray, function( index, value) {
 $('#employee_select').append("<option>"+ value + "</option>");
})
```

Thank you.

Comment: you need to fix the result coming from user.. share how you pass the result from the URL

Comment: Check that your returned string does not contain \n\n - which when you split it using \n - will create empy array elements that are then passed into the options. If you console.log(str) then you will be able to see the returned data baefore its split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a more elegant way of doing this but...

What if you pushed each result into an array and then ran a for loop through each item in array checking to see if each item is a string. The successful results of that, you push into a final array.

```
for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){
   if(typeof(array[i])=='string'){
     newArray.push(array[i])
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help so far!
I have updated my question. Can you please help?